# How to call a razor page from a Blazor component in a Server Side Blazor Application without causing a page refresh

Tags: authentication, razor, cookies, blazor

I am developing a Blazor Server Side Application which I need to include cookie authentication.  We created a custom login page component, but in order to create a cookie I need to call a Razor page to create the cookie.

Is there a way to call the razor page without doing a page refresh.

I tried using the UriHelper.NavigateTo but does not work with non Blazor component routes.

Then I tried with a Javascript call to do a window.location, but the issue is that this causes a browser refresh that makes all my instances to be recreated (like AppState, HttpClient), so all the information in these instances are lost (like httpclient headers, etc).

I expect to call the razor page to create a cookie, in a way that the httpclient and appstate scoped instance keep their values.

Comment: If you succeed, that _other_ page woud have the cookie. Not the page with your app. The S in SPA stands for Single.  The built-in authorization has all the right parts and steps. Use it or use it as a guideline. Login is a razor Page, not a Blazor component. For a reason.

Comment: Since the beginning we wanted to use the built in Blazor authentication, but the only problem that we have is that we could not find a way to customize the bland Login and Register pages.  We tried the Identity scaffolding but it has a bug in the latest Preview 8 with the latest Visual Studio 2019.  Any suggestion about how to customize these pages  until the bug is corrected ?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem. But I can't use the default login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We tried the Identity scaffolding but it has a bug in the latest Preview 8

I've seen that bug, easily corrected. You can scaffold now.  And otherwise,

> the only problem that we have is that we could not find a way to customize the bland Login and Register pages.

maybe you could live with those 'bland pages' until the release, end of September?

---

The steps, based on a Preview8 server-side project with "Individual user accounts"

NB: it is a good idea to Commit-changes in Git before and after this

- temporarily disable this line in Startup: `// endpoints.MapBlazorHub<App>(selector: "app");`
- run the scaffolding wizzard, add any pages you want
- uncomment the `endpoints.MapBlazorHub()` line again
- remove `Pages/_ViewStart.cshtml`
- fix `Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`, the first line is missing an `@using`
- fix `Pages/Shared/_Loginpartial.cshtml`, the second line is missing `@inject`

Compile and Run