# How do I customize ASP.NET Core Identity in Server-Side Blazor?

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-identity, blazor-server-side

For normal MVC-style websites, I get a set of pre-generated pages for ASP.NET Core Identity that I can customize. With it I can do things like ask for the user's age on the registration page.

What is the equivalent for server-side Blazor?

Comment: there is nothing available out-of-the-box right now.  however other projects like https://www.oqtane.org/ have forged ahead with their own initiatives in the area to provide `pure` blazor UI

Comment: @Jazb, pure Blazor UI ? This can easily achieved using Web Api endpoints and Jwt ! Do you have an idea how they did it ?

Comment: @Isaac - it's an open source project here: https://github.com/oqtane/oqtane.framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference you see is not directly related to Blazor but is present in all AspNetCore > 2.x projects.
The GUI is inside a set of 'canned' Razor pages inside a package.

When you have used the right starter template you should already see an Areas folder with a few files in it.

Right-click your project, choose Add, New Scaffolded Item, Identity.

The selected Razor pages are now extracted to your project and you can alter them. You will also need an `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {}` but that should be familiar.

---

You may need to fix a few things after applying the scaffolding. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57663817/60761

Comment: The scaffolding completely screwed up my layout, but I can go back and fix that. Otherwise this worked brilliantly.

Comment: Yes, you may need some post-fixing in Blazor.  It used to be worse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57663817/60761

Comment: I already noticed the missing `@using`. I'll go through that link to see if any of the other changes are still needed.

Comment: Most of it has been fixed by now, though I'm not sure about the extra _ViewStart.cshtml .

Comment: Just in case anyone was in my position; I tried scaffolding the identity pages on a default project and it screwed up the layout - none of the pages worked because they weren't wired properly. I was on `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` 3.1.1 and realised 3.1.2 was available. After the update to the package, everything works perfectly.